# Avatar - author box - misaligned CSS

Tags: css

Scroll down after the post to where you can see the red border avatar of the writer: http://designportugal.net/transformar-leads-em-vendas/

The avatar image is misaligned. It's below the text. I want to align it with it.

This is what I've tried:

```
.img-frame.left,
#container .img-frame.left {
float: left !important;
margin: -55px 20px 5px 0;
}
```

**-55px** is set to 5px currently. If I change it to -55px the image in the beginning of the post gets screwed up so I can't touch this selector.

I also tried this:

```
.img-frame .alignright,
.img-frame .alignleft,
.img-frame .alignnone,
.img-frame .aligncenter {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
```

The margin top above was previously set to 90px. Changing it on Chrome's inspector to 0px looks like it fixes it, but if go change it on my CSS file it doesn't work either.

I'm out of ideas. Note that this is a wordpress installation.

Comment: I don't see a -55px margin output on that first class, instead "margin: 5px 20px 5px 0;". Also you should avoid using !important, it doesn't solve a problem it hides it and can make things more difficult further down the line. Also, you should always set a width on floated items.

Comment: Right, there isn't a -55px margin, it's 5px. However I tried -55px but that would pull negatively all the left aligned images so I can't touch there. @OkamiStudio - Any clues? Btw thanks for the suggestion on the !important, I understand it should be for best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has eventually worked out by itself. CSS was not updating, but eventually did - and it wasn't a cache problem, he just didn't update the code differences. What a strange theme.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
img.alignleft.avatar.avatar-80.photo{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help. That didn't work but makes sense where you're going. I have no clue though. Btw you forgot the semi-colon at the end?

Comment: have you try using inline styling? like '<img style="margin:0;"/>' ?

Comment: Using inline styling in the avatar of the autor box? I can't do that because this is a wordpress installation.

Comment: yes you can, I think, if you can edit the stylesheet file then you can edit that too. Just try to find the element.

Comment: true must be some file in Wordpress that unfortunately I'm not able to check.

Answer (score 0):

It appears removing:

```
.img-frame .alignleft
```

from:

```
.img-frame .alignright, .img-frame .alignleft, .img-frame .alignnone, .img-frame .aligncenter {
margin: 90px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

works from a brief check in Chrome.

Or just set:

```
.img-frame .alignleft {
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: didn't work, I appreciate the help. There are some things that I change in Chrome's inspector, that, when I go change the style.css, nothing happens. Weird. Yours didn't work btw, but appreciate trying to help.